# Reloading an iFrame which was running an Applet

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet, href

I have a web page which is divided into several iFrames.

In each frame is a different solution, like JavaScript in one, flash in another, applet in another.

When a user interacts with the Applet, I am trying to provide a solution where if a certain event happens in the Applet, that the Applet will die and the same iFrame gets loaded with another solution (with an href like solution).  I want to be able to load another Applet, or a raw HTML solution, or whatever.

I suspect I need to wrap these solutions in something else like JavaScript, but wondering what would this solution look like.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See [Applet.getAppletContext().showDocument(url, target)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29).

Note that it is not guaranteed to be implemented in the JRE/browser combo. the applet is loaded in, let alone work.  That is where the JavaScript comes in.  ;)

Comment: I like this idea, I will need to investigate the potential.  Not sure I like the browser compatibility issue.